# Help needed with joining the two objects and baking

Tags: modifiers, workflow

I am doing a project in blender and I would like to add the corrugated surface onto the surface of the gun and then bake the normals for the gun. The gun is the low poly model and I guess the item named cube is the high poly one. Preferably I would like to have the entire surface of the gun covered with this sort of structure of the "cube" item with all the rows aligned along the same axis.
[image: This is the surface structure of that I want to give on the surface of the gun]
[image: This is the gun][image: This would be how the structure sits on the surface of the gun. the triangular shape faces outside][image: I have already tried the boolean modifier but as you can see it doesn't show a lot of the pieces as well as it takes away some of the gun model.]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oLJw.png) This is the surface structure that I want to give on the surface of the gun.
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU52p.png) This is the gun.
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHCRT.jpg) This would be how the structure sits on the surface of the gun. the triangular shape faces
outside.
[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhFeH.png) I have already tried the boolean modifier but as you can see it doesn't show a lot of the
pieces as well as it takes away some of the gun models.

I did try the blender guru video for normal baking and got the same artefacts as he did but I was not able to achieve the corrugated look in the normal. It looked flat. Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

- Duplicate gun, create structure object
- Select gun + structure + gun
- *Bake > Selected to active*. Enable **Cage** with some parametr.

[image]